# Android styles.xml errors

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am looking at an Android project that was made using Eclipse with ADT.

I have included a reference to **android-support-v7-appcompat.jar**.

In the res/values/styles.xml file I get this error:

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

In the res/values/themes.xml I get these types of errors:

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

etc...
```

It seems like I am just missing one little piece of configuration. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`jar`s do not include resources. You have to reference an `aar`.